# Compare a date without time part on jsp

Tags: java, jsp, date

I've looked a lot something about this, but all the answers I have found are, or too complicated or nor applicable to my particular problem.

Basically, I have 2 Dates, A and B. If A if the same day as today (no matter the time part), I have to show B; else, I have to show A.
My employer want to do this at jsp level, so I was using

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date"/>
```

And

```
<c:when test="${Object.dateA eq now}">
```

etc.

The problem is, when it's the same day, 'now' give me the date with the time part, because, I think, all "dates" are internally a simple number in unix timestamp format, so even if it's the same day, the 'eq' fails, because technically is NOT the same date (it's a couple of minutes 'later').
Do you know a clean way, at jsp level, to compare ONLY the date? maybe another operator rather than eq? or some way to transform the two dates to DD/MM/YYYY 00:00 ?

Comment: Please, if you found this question stupid, ignore it, but not add the usual "why do you want to do that when it's obvious that this X way is the right one". I MUST to do it this way because that's what my employer want, period.

Comment: Create your own JSP EL function, that transforms both Dates to a Calendar, and tests if the year, month and day are equal. You'll also need to specify a timezone. If you're on Java 8, consider using LocalDate instead of Date.